# The action of Lorentz transformations on 4-vectors in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, tensor-calculus

So I am studying special relativity and have been introduced to basic tensor calculus used in the theory. Recently, I came across a statement that is confusing me:  $$\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} x^\nu = x^\nu \Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu}$$
where $\Lambda^{u} _{v}$ is the Lorentz transformation matrix and $x^u$ is a 4-vector. Now what I don't understand is why this is the case? More specifically why is it possible to swap the order of the 4-vector and Lorentz matrix, I thought that matrix multiplication was not commutative and so this should be wrong.

Comment: Are you sure about the placement of the indices? Specifically, the $u$ index should appear in the bottom for the Lorentz transformation, not at the top. Otherwise, that's not a valid expression.

Comment: @enumaris oh sorry yeah I edited the question

Comment: ... and also are you sure there is no difference between $\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu}$, $\Lambda^{\,\,\mu}_\nu$ and $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I improved the "notation". I wasn't aware of the appropriate Mathjax syntax for the notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not swapping the order of the 4-vector and the Lorentz matrix, this notation is contracted. What this equation is saying is that: $$\sum_u\Lambda^{v} _{u} x^u =\sum_u x^u \Lambda^{v} _{u}$$

So the symbols in the summation are actually components of the vector and the matrix. Being components, just numbers, they surely commute, and you can change their order without any problems.

Comment: Ok so $$\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} x^\nu = \Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} x^0 + \Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} x^1 +\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} x^2 +\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} x^3$$ and NOT $$ \Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} \begin{pmatrix}x^0 \\ x^1 \\ x^2 \\ x^3 \end{pmatrix}$$? Am I right?

Comment: Almost, the right answer is:$$ \Lambda^\mu_{\,\,\nu} x^\nu = \Lambda^\mu_{\,\,0} x^0 + \Lambda^\mu_{\,\,1} x^1 +\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,2} x^2 +\Lambda^\mu_{\,\,3} x^3$$